# Making one term in a vocabulary priority and print it separately

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I have several terms in a vocabulary and my content type can be tagged with more than one of them.

When I print the term names tagged with the currently viewed node it seems that the term names are printed always in the same order (in the order of term id?)

However I somehow need to make one priority term per node and then print its term name first or separately from the rest.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a content taxonomy field and use that to select the highlight term.
http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy 
Then over ride or write your own theme function to loop through the terms array and remove the highlighted one before its output to the page

Comment: Thanks for your input but can you please specify me what "highlight term" means. I don't see anywhere to configure it for content taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest non coding way make a separate vocab and disable tags and multiple select for the new vocab then theme as required.

Comment: Thanks but all the terms need to be within the same vocabulary because I use them for also different things like argument and Views exposed filter.